# Loop through an array of objects and nested array

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to loop through an array of objects with a nested array. I need to access that nested array and display it to the browser.

```
const quizArray = [
    {
        id: 1,
        question: "What song starts with the line 'You've got a face for a smile you know'?",
        answer: "World of Chances",
        options: [
            "Everything You're Not",
            "World of Chances",
            "Mistake",
            "Everytime You Lie"
        ]
    },
]
const getquestions = () => {
    // Returns the array in a random order
    quizArray.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
    console.log(quizArray)

    const question = document.createElement('h2');
    question.innerHTML = quizArray[0].question;
    console.log(question)
    questionContainer.append(question)

}

const getPossibleOptions = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < quizArray.length; i++) {
        const options = document.createElement('button');
        options.innerHTML = quizArray[0].options[i];
        console.log(options)
        possibleOptions.append(options);
    }
}
```

I call both functions inside of another function with an event listener so that the question and options display after a start button is clicked.
The question displays no problem. But the options for the answers I’m having trouble with. It displays the 4 possible options but then it also displays 6 more buttons after it with each button saying undefined. I know it’s adding those 6 additional buttons because my quizArray is 10 items. I somehow need to access just the length of the options array.`

Comment: You should not be looping through `quizArray`, but `quizArray[0].options` instead. The for condition should be `for(let i = 0; i < quizArray[0].options.length; i++) `

Comment: Your way of shuffling the array can also be improved. Maybe you can have a look at how to apply a Fisher-Yates or Durstenfeld shuffle, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/2610061 ?

Comment: @LoveMegs _....I somehow need to access just the length of the options array._ You already know the answer, then what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop you are using `quizArray.length` which should be `quizArray[0].options.length` like the following:

```
const getPossibleOptions = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < quizArray[0].options.length; i++) {
        const optionButton = document.createElement('button');
        optionButton.innerHTML = quizArray[0].options[i];
        possibleOptions.append(optionButton);
    }
}
```